# Show jquery validation plugin messages without affecting nearby elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have following form.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">User Name:</label>
      <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="username" id="user" placeholder="Enter User name">
      <div class="error"></div>
    </div><br><br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password"  class="form-control" name="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password"><span class="errMsg"></span>
    </div>
```

And following jquery validation code,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            // Validate the form->see rules below
            $("#signUp_form").validate({
                         // On success of the form validation
                // submit AJAX
                submitHandler: function() {
                    // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "Sign_up.php",
                            data: $("#signUp_form").serialize(),
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data){
                             $("#signUp_form").trigger("reset");
                                    $("#response").html(data);
                                      location.href = "index.html"
                                }
                        });
                    return false;
                },
            // See jQuery validate() for more options for rules
            rules: {
                username: {
                    required: true,

                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8,
                },
                term: {
                    required: true,

                }

            },
            messages: {
                username: {
                    required:"<p style='color:red;'>Username is required!</p>",

                },
                password: {
                    required:"<p style='color:red;'>Password is required!</p>",
                    minlength: "<p style='color:red;'>password must be at least 8 charactors long!</p>"
                },

                 term: {
                    required:"<p style='color:red;'>To proceed you must be agree with our terms and conditions<img src='img/x.png' height='10px;width:10px;'/></p>",

                }

            }


        });
    });
```

Now my question is how to display error messages below input fields without re sizing form and without changing form elements' positions? Please help.

Comment: Since the plugin dynamically inserts the message elements into your layout, what do you propose should happen instead?  What do you want the layout to look like?   Once you can explain this, I can attempt to construct a solution using the options built into the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `errorPlacement` after `messages`.

```
messages: {
    //your code
},
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    //add span - element Id where you wish to show error
    error.appendTo("#" + $(element).attr('id') + "Err");
}
```